# permalink results to "page not found"

Tags: permalinks, mod-rewrite

Whenever I change my permalink option from the default to /%postname%/, it results into my page cannot be found.

Wordpress would complain that it cannot modify the .htaccess (because there was none), so I created it in /var/www/. The .htaccess has the same owner / permissions as my wordpress folder.

Please help, I've been trying to fix this for 3 days now.

Do I also need to change the mod_rewrite somewhere?

EDIT:

Solved!

inside /var/www/.htaccess
Add the line: Options +FollowSymLinks

for the mod_rewrite problem:

> Check for Apache Mod_ReWrite – Following lists all the loaded modules
>
> sudo apache2ctl -M Enable Mod_Rewrite
>
> sudo ln -s /etc/apache2/mods-available/rewrite.load
>   /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/rewrite.load Restart Apache view
>   sourceprint? 1 sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart

courtesy of https://usingnix.wordpress.com/2010/12/21/apache-mod_rewrite-wp-permalinks/

Comment: You don't 'change' mod_rewrite, really, but it needs to be enabled on the server and you need to have `AllowRide All` or (if I remember right) `AllowOveride File` in the server configuration. Are those conditions met?

Comment: I went to my /etc/apache2/httpd.conf. I'm suppose to uncomment a mod_rewrite line there but, my httpd.conf is empty except for one line: ServerTokens Prod. There are no other commented lines. Also where should I edit the AllowRide All

Comment: so apparently mod rewrite was not enabled. i enabled it but now there my pages say "forbidden 403"

Comment: Hi, paolo, you should add the Answer as a new... Answer. Not in the body of the Question, thanks and welcome!

Comment: Also, [the Codex is your friend](http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks#Using_.22Pretty.22_permalinks) ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!

inside /var/www/.htaccess
Add the line: Options +FollowSymLinks

for the mod_rewrite problem:

> Check for Apache Mod_ReWrite – Following lists all the loaded modules
>
> sudo apache2ctl -M Enable Mod_Rewrite
>
> sudo ln -s /etc/apache2/mods-available/rewrite.load
>   /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/rewrite.load Restart Apache view
>   sourceprint? 1 sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart

courtesy of https://usingnix.wordpress.com/2010/12/21/apache-mod_rewrite-wp-permalinks/

Answer (score 0):

I think there is enough information to make an answer. Really, only barely a WordPress questions but here you go.

First, be aware that the query-string format-- `?p=`, `?s=`, etc-- should always work.

This is for an Apache(2) server.

1. [`mod_rewrite`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) must be enabled
2. [`AllowOverride All`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#allowoverride) or at least `AllowOverride File` must be set
3. The `.htaccess` file must be properly created. WordPress will write the file if it can, otherwise go to the wp-admin->Settings->Permalinks, and save the permalinks. If WordPress complains that it can't write the `.htaccess` file then copy what WordPress tells you into `.htaccess` manually. This is a required part of the process.
4. [Check the permissions.](http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_File_Permissions#.htaccess_permissions)